# How to properly use the call (or delegatecall) in solidity

Tags: call, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, binance

I'm trying to use this method:

```
function test(uint amount) public {
        address(0xf5eA38B6b9644224dA1aECbC1219e8543c0689b2).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit(uint)",amount));
    }
```

but the transaction gets reverted, this is because the amount is not hashed in some way, and I don't really know to do it, what should I do on the amount? these are transactions:

-the failed one using the method: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x7fdd50cee23295ea866baa8961a2105c58162e77125df852a4fc5bf0fad2f507

and this was the input data:

Function: test(uint256 tAmount) ***

MethodID: 0x29e99f07
[0]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

-the successfull one directly calling the contract from the site instead of using call inside another smart contract: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xfd4158766f25761fa5dddb0683c677085a04ea6db05e03794be375a8243d7128

and this was the input data:

Function: deposit(uint256 _amount) ***

MethodID: 0xb6b55f25
[0]:  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005427aedb41a400

do I need to hash amount in someway?

Answer (score 1):

The target contract defines `uint` as the argument type, but it's just an alias `uint256`. ABI encode methods don't automatically convert the aliases, so you need to change it in your code.

```
// `uint256` instead of `uint`
abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit(uint256)",amount)
```

Comment: Already tried, doesn't change anything, the transaction gets reverted anyway

Comment: @CarloParisi Transaction can revert for a number of reasons, including a failing `require()` statement inside the funciton body (or the function dependencies such as other functions and external contracts that it calls). My snippet solves one of the reasons and that is calculating the correct function signature. Unfortunately solving all possible reasons why a transaction can fail is usually out of scope for a StackOverflow answer, but I suggest you to debug the execution trace, look for `require` and `assert` statements that might cause the tx to revert.

Comment: I'm looking at the VM trace, but it is assembly and it is quite hard to understand, following the called function I should pass all the require/modifiers
Is there something easier than the VM trace?

Comment: My usual approach is to read the contract source code and look for `require` and `assert` statements, including in all functions (possibly in other contracts) that it calls. If you don't have the target contract(s) source code, then yea, it's going to be a bit complicated and you'll need to use VM trace or a similar tool (my favorite is Panoramix, [included](https://bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x2170ed0880ac9a755fd29b2688956bd959f933f8) in BscScan).